# Please let me know the possible solutions of implementing another Navigation bar in Service Console

Tags: console

By default Service Console built for Salesforce Classic Application has one Navigation bar . We have a requirement in which the users wants to have many navigation bars like one for Cases [by default one], other for Knowledge, other for Accounts and so on.

Please suggest how can it be implemented and also will it affect the performance and responsiveness for the Agents. Any suggestions are welcome.

[image].As in the picture Cases is shown now in the red boxes want other Objects of Salesforce Service Cloud

Comment: can you post a picture of your ask for better understanding

Comment: Edited the post and added the picture as requested for more clarity

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you

Comment: Santanu thanks for your answer but the agents really want to have multiple navigation bars. I will let you know if it works for me and the agents. Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce console by default supports only one navigation bar and navigation items are grouped as displayed as drop down.

Though, you can provide an option for users to `Show Customize My Tabs on the Navigation Tab`, in console app configuration.

Then, user will see an extra item in the dropdown as follows:

[image: customize my tabs]

Upon clicking the link user can change the tabs as per their convenience.

[image: Navigation tab]